# Can't change text of a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have created 2 `UITextField`s and a `UIButton` programmatically, when I click the `UIButton` I want it to change the text of the highlighted `UITextField` but it's changing the text of the second `UITextField` not the highlighted one.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    txtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 45)];
    txtf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    txtf.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    txtf.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    txtf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txtf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    txtf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    txtf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:txtf];

    txtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 345)];
    txtf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    txtf.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    txtf.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    txtf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txtf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    txtf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    txtf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:txtf];
}

- (IBAction)change:(id)sender 
{
    txtf.text = @"the text was changed"
}
```

is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighted text field"? The one having focus?

Comment: @Antonio yes I mean the focused text field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
txtf1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 45)];
txtf1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
txtf1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtf1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
txtf1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtf1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtf1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtf1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
txtf1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:txtf1];

txtf2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 345)];
txtf2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
txtf2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtf2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
txtf2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtf2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtf2.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtf2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
txtf2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:txtf2];
}

- (IBAction)change:(id)sender {
txtf2.text = @"the text was changed"
}
```

And add txtf2 to class members.

**UPDATE**:
To change highlighted `UITextField` modify `- (IBAction)change:(id)sender` to

```
- (IBAction)change:(id)sender 
{
    if ( txtf1.isHighlighted ) {
        txtf1.text = @"the text 1 was changed";
    }
    else if ( txtf2.isHighlighted ) {
        txtf2.text = @"the text 2 was changed";
    }  
    else {
        NSLog(@"none of the textField is Highlighted");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
When you have a lot of text fields you can try following

```
for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = subview;
        if (textField.isHighlighted) {
            textField.text = @"the text was changed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed `txtf` to `txtf1` and `txtf2`

Comment: I used this method, but what I want is to change the text of the highlighted text field how to know if this highlighted or not

Comment: Please make this known it your answer then.

Comment: @Avt that exactly what I wanted, but is there is anyway to change the text of any highlighted text field, to use it if I have many text fields

Comment: @KevinMartin you can either you an array or use viewtags

Answer (score 2):

`txtf` always points to second textField. so thats the problem.

When you created the first `UItextFied`, `txtf` points to it. But when you create a new `UITextField` and make txtf point to it, **then reference with first textField is lost**.

And in your `change` method, you are always getting the `reference of second textfield` and changing it.

Two options,
 1) use `txtf1` and `txtf2`, two class properties
 2) use tags. `[UIView viewWithTag:tagValue]`;

**Using Tag's->**
Assuming **numberOfTextFields** you using is 3.

```
txtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 45)];
//set its properties
txtf.tag=1;
[self.view addSubview:txtf];

txtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 45)];
//set its properties
txtf.tag=2;
[self.view addSubview:txtf];

txtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 45)];
//set its properties
txtf.tag=3;
[self.view addSubview:txtf];
```

Modify change method to

```
- (IBAction)change:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger numberOfTextFields=3;
    UITextField *textField;
    for (int i=1; i<=numberOfTextFields; i++) {
        textField=(UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if(textField.isHighlighted==YES)
            break;
        else
            textField=nil;
    }

    if(textField==nil){
        NSLog(@"none is highlightes");
    }
    else{
        textField.text= @"new text for highlighted textField";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your both `UITextField` has same name ***(txtf)***, So first change the name of either first or second `UITextField`. Other wise you code is correct. :)

**EDITED :**

Just make more correct **@Avt's** updated answer.

```
- (IBAction)change:(id)sender 
{
    if ( txtf1.isHighlighted ) {
        txtf1.text = @"the text 1 was changed";
    }
    else if ( txtf2.isHighlighted ) {
        txtf2.text = @"the text 2 was changed";
    }  
    else {
        NSLog(@"none of the textField is Highlighted");
    }
}
```